# What does "I live this" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "I live this" mean here? "I'm a good fit for this deal"?

> To sell his offer, Cuban pointed out that he already has a portfolio of plant-based companies and knows how to successfully market Pan’s product. “I’ve done this before. We already have Alyssa’s [vegan cookies], we have Snacklins, Unreal Deli. And I’m a vegetarian. So, I live this,” Cuban said.

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2020/11/23/shark-tank-mark-cuban-invests-in-founder-selling-vegan-jerky.html

Comment: He's expressing his enthusiasm at the idea of marketing vegetarian food whilst being a vegetarian. And perhaps he doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Thank you very much